# Defining an objective function for a Shift Optimization Algoritm

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to write a shift optimization algorithm using PuLP library in Python. But I am facing an error in my onjective function.

The main goal of this program is to distribute each worker to their shifts based on the weight of that shift.

So, if shift A has more sales, it will have more workers than the other two.

I wrote the following objective function, but sadly this does not work as planned:

```
def create_objective_function(variables, days, employees):
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, _ = variables
    obj_shift_weights = pulp.LpAffineExpression()

    # Objective function to enforce the desired number of workers for each shift
    weight_morning = 0.3
    weight_evening = 0.2
    weight_night = 0.5

    for i in range(days):
        for j in range(employees):
            # Enforce the desired number of workers for each shift based on the weights
            obj_shift_weights += var_Sabah[i][j] * weight_morning
            obj_shift_weights += var_Aksam[i][j] * weight_evening
            obj_shift_weights += var_Gece[i][j] * weight_night

    obj = obj_shift_weights

    return obj
```

Here is the full script:

```
import pulp
import math
import json
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def create_variables(days, employees):
    # Create binary decision variables for each shift and day
    var_Sabah = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("8_16", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
    var_Aksam = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("16_24", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
    var_Gece = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("24_8", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
    var_Tatil = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("00", (range(days), range(employees)), 0, 1, "Binary")
    return var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, var_Tatil

def create_objective_function(variables, days, employees):
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, _ = variables
    obj_shift_weights = pulp.LpAffineExpression()

    # Objective function to enforce the desired number of workers for each shift
    weight_morning = 0.3
    weight_evening = 0.2
    weight_night = 0.5

    for i in range(days):
        for j in range(employees):
            # Enforce the desired number of workers for each shift based on the weights
            obj_shift_weights += var_Sabah[i][j] * weight_morning
            obj_shift_weights += var_Aksam[i][j] * weight_evening
            obj_shift_weights += var_Gece[i][j] * weight_night

    obj = obj_shift_weights

    return obj




def add_worker_assignment_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees):
    # Add constraints to ensure each worker is assigned to exactly one shift each day
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, var_Tatil = variables
    for i in range(days):
        for j in range(employees):
            c = None
            c += var_Sabah[i][j] + var_Aksam[i][j] + var_Gece[i][j] + var_Tatil[i][j]
            problem += c == 1

def add_minimum_resource_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees, week, processid):
    # Add constraints to ensure a minimum number of workers for each shift
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, _ = variables
    total_shifts = 3 * days
    work_days = 5 * week
    worker_per_shift_avg = (employees * work_days) / total_shifts 
    worker_per_shift_min = math.floor(worker_per_shift_avg) - processid
    
    for i in range(days):
        for shift in [var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece]:
            worker_per_shift = None
            for j in range(employees):
                worker_per_shift += shift[i][j]
            problem += worker_per_shift >= worker_per_shift_min

def add_day_off_constraints(problem, var_Tatil, days, employees):
    # Add constraints to prohibit consecutive days off
    for j in range(employees):
        for i in range(days - 1):
            c = None
            c += var_Tatil[i][j] + var_Tatil[i+1][j]
            problem += c <= 1

def add_shift_change_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees):
    # Add constraints to prohibit shift changes without a day off in between
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, var_Tatil = variables
    for j in range(employees):
        for i in range(days - 1):
            c = None
            d = None
            e = None
            c += var_Sabah[i][j] + var_Aksam[i + 1][j] + var_Gece[i + 1][j]
            d = var_Aksam[i][j] + var_Gece[i + 1][j] + var_Sabah[i + 1][j]
            e = var_Gece[i][j] + var_Sabah[i + 1][j] + var_Aksam[i + 1][j]
            problem += c <= 1
            problem += d <= 1
            problem += e <= 1

def add_weekly_work_constraints(problem, variables, employees, days_per_week, week):
    # Add constraints to ensure each worker works 5 days in a week
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, _ = variables
    for j in range(employees):
        c = None
        for k in range(week):
            c = None
            for i in range(days_per_week):
                c += var_Sabah[i + days_per_week * k][j] + var_Aksam[i + days_per_week * k][j] + var_Gece[i + days_per_week * k][j]
            problem += c == 5

def extract_shift_assignments(problem, variables, employees, days):
    # Extract the shift assignments from the solved problem
    shift_assignments = {}
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, var_Tatil = variables
    for j in range(employees):
        shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"] = {}
        for i in range(days):
            for shift, var_shift in [("Morning", var_Sabah), ("Afternoon", var_Aksam), ("Night", var_Gece), ("DayOff", var_Tatil)]:
                if pulp.value(var_shift[i][j]) == 1:
                    shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"][f"Day {i+1}"] = shift
    return shift_assignments

def write_to_json(shift_assignments, filename):
    # Write the shift assignments to a JSON file
    with open(filename, "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(shift_assignments, json_file, indent=4)
    print(f"Shift assignments have been written to '{filename}'.")

def count_shifts(shift_assignments, days_per_week, week, employees, variables):
    # Count the total shifts and weekly worker counts
    var_Tatil = variables[3]
    shift_counts = {"Morning": 0, "Afternoon": 0, "Night": 0}
    weekly_counts = {f"Week {k+1}": {"Monday": 0, "Tuesday": 0, "Wednesday": 0, "Thursday": 0, "Friday": 0, "Saturday": 0, "Sunday": 0} for k in range(week)}
    days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    for k in range(week):
        for i in range(days_per_week):
            for j in range(employees):
                day_index = i + k * days_per_week
                if f"Worker {j+1}" in shift_assignments and f"Day {day_index+1}" in shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"]:
                    shift = shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"][f"Day {day_index+1}"]
                    if shift != "DayOff":
                        if shift == "Morning":
                            shift_counts["Morning"] += 1
                        elif shift == "Afternoon":
                            shift_counts["Afternoon"] += 1
                        elif shift == "Night":
                            shift_counts["Night"] += 1

    for k in range(week):
        for i in range(days_per_week):
            for j in range(employees):
                day_index = i + k * days_per_week
                if f"Worker {j+1}" in shift_assignments and f"Day {day_index+1}" in shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"]:
                    shift = shift_assignments[f"Worker {j+1}"][f"Day {day_index+1}"]
                    if shift != "DayOff":
                        weekly_counts[f"Week {k+1}"][days_of_week[i]] += 1

    return shift_counts, weekly_counts


def main():
    # Set the problem parameters
    employees = 50
    days_per_week = 7
    week = 4
    days = days_per_week * week
    num_processes = 4

    processes = []

    for process_id in range(num_processes):
        # Create decision variables
        variables = create_variables(days, employees)

        # Create the optimization problem with the chosen solver
        problem = pulp.LpProblem("Shift", pulp.LpMinimize)
        obj = create_objective_function(variables, days, employees)
        problem += obj

        # Add constraints
        add_worker_assignment_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees)
        add_minimum_resource_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees, week, process_id)
        add_day_off_constraints(problem, variables[3], days, employees)
        add_shift_change_constraints(problem, variables, days, employees)
        add_weekly_work_constraints(problem, variables, employees, days_per_week, week)

        # Create and start a process for each optimization problem
        p = Process(target=solve_and_write, args=(problem, variables, employees, days, process_id, days_per_week, week))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Wait for all processes to finish
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

def solve_and_write(problem, variables, employees, days, process_id, days_per_week, week):
    # Solve the problem
    problem.solve()

    if pulp.LpStatus[problem.status] != "Optimal":
        print(f"Optimization problem for process {process_id} is not solvable optimally.")
    else:
        # Extract solution and write to JSON with process_id
        shift_assignments = extract_shift_assignments(problem, variables, employees, days)
        json_filename = f"schedule_process_{process_id}.json"
        write_to_json(shift_assignments, json_filename)

        # Count and display shift and weekly worker counts
        shift_counts, weekly_counts = count_shifts(shift_assignments, days_per_week, week, employees, variables)

        # Write the output to a text file
        txt_filename = f"output_process_{process_id}.txt"
        with open(txt_filename, "w") as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(f"\nTotal Shift Counts for process {process_id}:\n")
            for shift, count in shift_counts.items():
                txt_file.write(f"{shift}: {count}\n")

            txt_file.write(f"\nWeekly Worker Counts for process {process_id}:\n")
            for week_num, counts in weekly_counts.items():
                txt_file.write(f"\nWeek {week_num} Worker Counts:\n")
                for day, count in counts.items():
                    txt_file.write(f"{day}: {count}\n")

        print(f"Output for process {process_id} has been written to '{txt_filename}'.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Some notes about the script:
-There are three shift, and a holiday array.
-I wanted more than one outputs, and playing with min_resource_constraint seemed as a good way, So I created a multiprocess program that sets it based on the pid.

But as I stated, the outputs (in .txt files) does not seem to work well.

How can I implement an objective function that solves this problem.

Thanks for your help.

I played with constand weight values to see if that is the problem.

I also tried another version of my objective function that tries to minimize the difference:

```
def create_objective_function(variables, days, employees):
    var_Sabah, var_Aksam, var_Gece, _ = variables
    obj_shift_weights = pulp.LpAffineExpression()

    # Objective function to minimize the deviation from shift weights
    weight_morning = 0.8
    weight_evening = 0.8
    weight_night = 0.4

    for i in range(days):
        for j in range(employees):
            obj_shift_weights += (var_Sabah[i][j] - weight_morning)
            obj_shift_weights += (var_Aksam[i][j] - weight_evening)
            obj_shift_weights += (var_Gece[i][j] - weight_night)

    obj = obj_shift_weights

    return obj
```

This also did not work.

Lastly, I tried to enforce it as a constraint but failed to do so.

Update: Since the post seemed a bit abstract on the errors, I wanted to add some outputs.

The following output is generated when the weights of the shifts are 0.3 for the night, 0.5 for the evening, and 0.2 for the morning:

`Total Shift Counts for process 3: Morning: 552 Afternoon: 224 Night: 224`

This is obtained in the most flexible process, where min_resource_constraint is 'min_resource_constraint - 4'.

Please note that the smaller the weights, the more workers are required to work even considering that the script does not do what it should.

Comment: Please be more specific about what isn't working. What error are you getting? What results do you expect, and how do your current results differ?

Comment: Sorry for my abstract explanation.

As I stated, I declared some weights for each shift and expected the distribution to be made considering them. But this is not the in the outputs.

For debugging, I had some print statements, which showed the distribution of workers among the shifts. And the following is the output (in the most flexible process) with weight values being:

`weight_morning = 0.2
    weight_evening = 0.5
    weight_night = 0.3`

And the output is as follows:

`Total Shift Counts for process 3:
Morning: 552
Afternoon: 224
Night: 224'

Which is far from expected.

Comment: I don't think you can trace a demand curve using just weights in the objective. You need to explicitly measure deviation from the demand curve and minimize that. Note that it is unusual that you have not a fully specified demand curve, but only the shape.